# Passing track_total_hits Param via WFS Query through GeoServer to ElasticSearch Backend

Tags: geoserver, wfs, query, elasticsearch

We are executing WFS 1.1.0 based queries via a GeoServer instance (2.18) backed by an ElasticSearch datastore (v7.x - not sure of the specific version), and are looking to retrieve an accurate Hit count for the results. However based on the version of Elastic (v7.x) we need to provide an additional parameter to each query, namely "track_total_hits": true.

My attempts thus far have centred around use of [Native Queries](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/elasticsearch/index.html#native-queries) and using the "viewParams=q:{query_body}". I have managed to pass through Queries to ElasticSearch, however the additional track_total_hits param is being ignored/not passed through. I have been using XML format WFS GetFeature queries, specifying the viewParams attribute.

Some attempts included (not conforming to Elastic query formats I know, but was getting desperate):

1. viewParams=q:{"match_all":{}},"track_total_hits":true
2. viewParams=q:{"match_all":{},track_total_hits:true}
3. viewParams=q:{"match_all":{},"track_total_hits":true}
4. viewParams=q:{"match_all":{}},{"track_total_hits":true}

Is this possible?